# Create an image grid view in android

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I need to create an image gridview in my android activity. How can it be achieved..I have seen a gridview and used it. Also I have used the image view in my activities. But I donot know how to create a grid view using images. Can someone shed some light regarding this? Any help from anyone is appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly you want the layout to be ? and also what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customizes the grid view with your own adapter class derived from **BaseAdapter**. Please use the following code:

Adapter Class:

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

```
public Drawable[] images;

public ImageAdapter(Context c,Drawable[] d){
    mContext = c;
    images=d;
}

public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(images[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Assign this adapter to your grid view as **gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(GridImages.this,images));**

Comment: I need to add the images to the grid view from a folder in my sd card. How can it be acheived?? Please help me out..

Comment: Please load the images from sdcard using Bitmap Factory as follows Bitmap gridImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file_name"); and please change the adapter constructor parameter Drawable[] to Bitmap[].

Answer (score 0):

You might use also the TableLayout and set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`to image to fill the cell and after manage your cells and rows as you want.